# Bing geocoder sometimes return the correct number of records and sometimes none

Tags: c#, wpf, bing-api, bing-maps

I'm using Bing Map API in my WPF Application to pin the list of addresses to my WPF UI but sometimes I get no result when using this block of code, and sometimes it does return the correct number of records.

How to fix this issue? Why sometime bing-map responses are abnormal?

```
using Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using Ravager.BingMapsService;
using Ravager.Shell.UI;

namespace Ravager.MappingPlugins.MapViewModel
 {
public class GeoCodeResultByAddress
{
    public async static Task<List<GeocodeResult>> GeocodeAddress(List<string> addres)//async Task<>
    {
        List<GeocodeResult> GeocodeResult = new List<GeocodeResult>();
        foreach (var address in addres)
        {
            try
            {
                GeocodeResult res = null;
                if (!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(address) && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(address)))
                {

                int Counts = 0;
                again: using (GeocodeServiceClient client = new GeocodeServiceClient("CustomBinding_IGeocodeService"))
                    {
                        GeocodeRequest request = new GeocodeRequest();
                        request.Credentials = new Credentials() { ApplicationId = (App.Current.Resources["MyCredentials"] as ApplicationIdCredentialsProvider).ApplicationId };
                        request.Query = address;                     

                       GeocodeResponse respons = await Task.Run(() => client.Geocode(request));

                        res = respons.Results.Count > 0 ? respons.Results[0] : null;

                        if (res != null)
                        {
                            GeocodeResult.Add(res);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (Counts < 3)
                            {
                                Counts++;
                                goto again;
                            }
                            MessageBox.Show("Unable to Generate GeocodeAddress for " + address);
                        }
                    }
                }

                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Unable to Generate GeocodeAddress");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }

        }
        return GeocodeResult;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This has been answered several times before. You are more than likely being rate limited. This occurs to trial and basic Bing Maps keys when either your account is consuming transactions at a rate that will exceed the free terms of use, or when the service is under a lot of load from others who are using Bing Maps under the free terms of use. The only way to limit the possibility of being rate limited is to upgrade to an Enterprise key.

When rate limiting occurs to a request a flag is added in the header of the response to indicate this has happened. This is documented here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701703.aspx